# INITIAL_STATE injection token with new createreducer function

Tags: ngrx

With the new createReducer function in ngrx8 I'm trying to work out how you would use it with the INITIAL_STATE injection token from '@ngrx/store';

In the old world you could do something like:

providers: [{ provide: INITIAL_STATE, useValue: { initialState: initialState } }]

and this would hydrate the state parameter of the reducer function to be your initial state

However as the first parameter is the initial state, I'm trying to work out how you would inject the INITIAL_STATE?

Cheers

James

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it, the `INITIAL_STATE` token has not been changed.

Comment: Hi Tim

Yes that did work, I'd reordered ny imports which was causing a problem...

Though I'm now left with:

`
const actionsReducer: ActionReducer<any> = createReducer(**whatgoeshere**?,
....
on(actions.reset, (state: any) => {
     return **and here if i want to set reset to initial state**
})
`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: the same parameter as you would do in a normal reducer, in your case 2x initalState ?

Comment: Sorry I must be confused, I've setup the INITIAL_STATE token like this:
```
StoreModule.forFeature('features', reducer, INITIAL_STATE)
 providers: 
 [
        {
          provide: INITIAL_STATE,
          useValue: { initialState: { optiona: true, optionb: false } }
        }
]
```

So I don't have access the initial state in the reducer.

So I'm trying to work out how to access the INITIAL_STATE injection token value in the reducer

I tried doing this: inject(INITIAL_STATE)

But it didn't like it as the reducer is not in a class

Comment: how did you do it with the reducer function previous versions? Please share some code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comment, you try to use the initial state token in a feature module - unfortunately this isn't possible. The token can only be used in the root module:

> The `INITIAL_STATE` token is only used to set the initial state of the root module.
>   You could use the OnInitEffect lifecycle or the @ngrx/store/update-reducers action to dispatch a "set action" to set the state of the feature module in a reducer.

See this [Github Link](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2534) for more info.